# How to call jQuery function from Flash

Tags: jquery, externalinterface

I have a problem only with IE: if I try to invoke a JS function from Flash using `ExternalInterface` I cannot get results if Flash is embedded inside a JQuery dialog. When I make the same thing from a normal HTML page it runs.

How can I invoke `ExternalInterface.call` to run a function even if flash is inside a dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE the Flash embed `OBJECT` tag should have an **`id`**, otherwise `ExternalInterface` won't work.

I'm not sure though how you can add an id to Flash embed tag inside the UI dialog.

Comment: I've put id attribute to OBJECT tag but it still does not work :-)

Comment: Are you sure the Flash in the dialog is not inside an `iframe` tag?